# Is there a way where I can design a program in a graphical way?

Tags: graphics, ide

I was wondering if there is a way to design a program in a graphical way. What I mean is that if its possible to have, for example, the classes on the screen as little child windows and that there is inside a list box with all the properties, functions, subs. and that the classes that inherit each other are joined by a line.

Hopefully you understood me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like every UML tool that I know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [squeak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeak) and [scratch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scratch_%28programming_language%29). Squeak is an implementation of smalltalk *the* pioneering object oriented language. If you are familiar with ruby you will see a lot of similarities.